# What's the correct way to cancel an operation with a callback on a disposable object?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, cancellation

I'm working on porting a controller to async. Part of the work involves awaiting an async, cancel-able operation on a disposable object using a cancellation token that's valid for the life of the request. In this particular case it's `WebClient.UploadStringTaskAsync(Uri uri, string data)`.

I know the correct way to cancel a WebClient's async operations using `cancellationToken.Register(() => webClient.CancelAsync())`. However, the `WebClient` is created in a using statement, so it's disposed at the end of the block. As a result, calling `webClient.CancelAsync()` from a callback rightfully results in an "Access to disposed closure" warning. I found that `CancellationToken.Register(Action callback)` results in a `CancellationTokenRegistration` object that implements `IDisposable` and unregisters callbacks upon disposal. In the end, my code looks like:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
using (cancellationToken.Register(() => webClient.CancelAsync())
{
     await webClient.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, data);
}

// cancellationToken can be cancelled later.
```

I've made a console app to show that code with the same spirit works and cancelling the token after the disposable object and token registration have been disposed doesn't result in the disposable object's callback being called. I want to be certain though: Is this correct and safe?

**Edit:** I suppose I should rephrase my question a little bit. What's the standard solution for using a cancellation token to cancel an async operation on a disposable object where the operation only supports cancellation through registering a callback?

Comment: "Cancelling the token after the disposable object and token registration have been disposed doesn't result in the disposable object's callback being called" - why would you expect `CancellationTokenRegistration`'s callback to be invoked otherwise?

Comment: @Dai I don't, but I also couldn't find any direct example to rely on and I don't want to make assumptions.

Comment: Without a good [mcve], no one can tell you for sure what the code will do. There are too many possibilities. Since the source code for `CancellationToken` is public, _you_ can inspect it yourself and know for sure what it will do in _your_ specific scenario. Your question does not appear answerable as-is. Based on the code you posted, it doesn't seem possible that your `WebClient` could get disposed while the callback was still registered, as that'd be again the C# specification rules. But how are we to know for sure what the rest of the code is doing?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Maybe I wasn't clear, but I'm more concerned about the general case and its standard solution of "What's the best practice for cancelling an async method on a disposable object that doesn't support cancellation tokens?"

Comment: Questions having the form _"What's the best practice..."_ are practically always either too broad, primarily opinion based, or (most often) both. Especially since disposable objects that don't support cancellation tokens have a wide variety of _other_ mechanisms for cancelling. It just depends on the object.

Comment: I don't understand your edited question. The object you're using as an example, `WebClient`, itself does not use a callback for cancellation. I think maybe you mean, cancelling via a `CancelToken` requires registration of a callback, but that's not at all clear from what you actually wrote, and there certainly are other mechanisms that could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this correct and safe?

Yes.

> What's the standard solution for using a cancellation token to cancel an async operation on a disposable object where the operation only supports cancellation through registering a callback?

Ideally, operations take a `CancellationToken` directly. In this case, the approach you already have is fine.